# Writing id3 metadata to mp3 file in application bundle

Tags: iphone, xcode, avaudioplayer, id3

I've asked this question twice before, with no real progress. After trolling countless forum after forum, I've come to ask again. The only progress so far with this is accessing the metadata of an AVURLAsset (using `[AVURLAsset commonMetadata]`). There are C libraries out there for writing id3 tags (such as [id3lib](http://id3lib.sourceforge.net/)) but none are configured for Cocoa Touch or even Xcode. Any sort of help would be appreciated, even a suggestion of the right direction to go would be greatly appreciated. If you solve the problem, you'll get an honorable mention in my finished app...

Comment: I've got a similar 'problem': http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658386/audiofilesetproperty-returning-kaudiofileunsupportedpropertyerror-pty

Comment: Yeah so it seems we've taken different approaches, but neither one of us has had much progress. I'm actually rather shocked that Apple has made it so dang hard to write info to a mp3. The one thing I haven't tried yet is writing the actual bytes of information at the most basic level... I'd really prefer to have something a little nicer than that though. On another note, I've gotten it to work with little trouble on Android using [MyID3](http://www.fightingquaker.com/myid3/)

Comment: Some people pointed me to the c library called "id3lib": http://id3lib.sourceforge.net/, but haven't got that one working either.

Comment: Yeah I spent a few days trying to get it to work (there are reports of people building it into an Obj-C Framework, but I could never get that)...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just ported idlib3 to iOS and you can use it to modify the ID3 tag. An example project is also included. Check it here https://github.com/rjyo/libid3-ios

Comment: Dude, thank you *SOOO* much, I've been searching for this for a solid 8 months now...