# How to edit mp3 ID3 tags in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++, id3

I'm trying to edit some mp3 ID3 tags in objective-c. So far I haven't managed to get any further then when I started. I have had a look at the [tagLib](http://developer.kde.org/~wheeler/taglib.html#building) but I can't seem to get it into my project. Well, I don't know which files I have to add. *A tutorial maybe?*

Using apples `AudioFileSetProperty()` also didn't work. I was able to read the tags though but when writing i got this error: `pty?`. I am not the only one with this problem: [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658386/audiofilesetproperty-returning-kaudiofileunsupportedpropertyerror-pty)

So does anyone know an "easy" ID3 library? It doesn't need to be Objective-c only as I am developing for the Mac.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am going to tackle this soon myself.

What I plan on using is AVFoundation. This is for 10.7 or greater, that is the one downfall.

Otherwise you just export a session to an AVURLAsset. Will post more as I get into this.

Comment: Great! Hopefully you can do this :) It is ashame though that it will only work on 10.7